# How to get financial, 1st and last date of each month of whole year

Tags: jquery, calendar, financial

[Financial Year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeFuh.png)

I want to get financial year by using Jquery, Check the example as i have 12 fields and every field is having a month name and in the same row it also shows the 1st and last date of month, some how i reached at the point but unable to get such results.

```js
var theMonths = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var date = new Date();
  var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(theMonths[i]), 1);
  var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  var months = '<li class="' + theMonths[i] + '">' + theMonths[i] + ' - - - - - -  ' + firstDay + '---------' + lastDay + '</li>';
  $('.calenderYear .month').append(months);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calenderYear">
  <ul class="month"></ul>
  <span class="dates"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're providing a text value from your array to the `month` parameter of the `Date` object constructor. That value should be an integer.

Therefore your array is redundant, you can just pass `i` and `i + 1` respectively.

Also note that your output starts at July with the Financial year. To do that you can add an offset to the iterating variable, and use the modulo operator to ensure it wraps around to the starting months of the following year.

Finally, The `lastDay` should technically be at `23:59:59`, not `00:00:00`, otherwise there's an almost 24 hour period which isn't covered.

Try this:

```js
var theMonths = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var offset = 6;

for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var date = new Date();
  var monthIndex = i + offset;
  var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), monthIndex % theMonths.length, 1);
  var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), monthIndex + 1 % theMonths.length, 0, 23, 59, 59);
  var months = '<li class="' + theMonths[i] + '"><p>' + theMonths[monthIndex % theMonths.length] + '</p><p>' + firstDay + '</p><p>' + lastDay + '</p></li>';
  $('.calenderYear .month').append(months);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="calenderYear">
  <ul class="month"></ul>
  <span class="dates"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you buddy you saved my life :)

Comment: One thing more, can you please let me know how to get this auromatically and how can i format date only, as it show standard time etc.

and also if i have a text field where i give only month (any) it starts from that month

Comment: Date formatting is a pain in JS. I'd suggest you use a library such as Date.js or Moment.js. You can do it manually though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Comment: Is it posible to do it without library? and get financial year with custom given month,

Comment: Brother your code works very fine but when new year starts it shows January 2018 but it shows Undefined and adter it show the date which is really fine. please help,

Comment: Thank you very much dear, its great now please help me in generating auto month with given custom month name, suppose if i give January then year starts from January and generate remaining months, or if i give August so it starts from August and generate remaining months. also formating the date please without any library. Thanks